# stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding not converting some special characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsstring

In my app i'm using `stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` for converting special characters. But some characters (like &,-,') not converting.

Sting before conertion: Macklemore & Ryan Lewis - Can't Hold Us

Sting after conertion: `Macklemore%20&%20Ryan%20Lewis%20-%20Can't%20Hold%20Us`

In the above string there in no change of `&,-,'`

How can I solve this issue. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Example**

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self urlEncodeUsingEncoding:kCFStringEncodingUTF8 WithURLString:@"&-"]);
```

// Add Special Charcter

```
    - (NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(CFStringEncoding)encoding WithURLString:(NSString *)strUrl {

    return CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                     ( CFStringRef)strUrl,
                                                                     NULL,
                                                                     CFSTR("!*'()+$#[]&-"),
                                                                     encoding));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding in place of NSUTF8StringEncoding

```
stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding
```